# Is possible to set a default value as an attribute in an element with other facets defined (XSD)?

Tags: xsd, attributes, element, default-value

Suppose I have:

```
<xs:element name="fieldName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <osd:otherFacets>
                <osd:tableRef>
                    <tablePath>/root/TargetTable</tablePath>
                    <filter>
                        <predicate>./targetTableField = "status"</predicate>
                    </filter>
                </osd:tableRef>
            </osd:otherFacets>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

The possible values for fieldName are filtered by status. However, in this case, it is necessary to set a default value as being the PK of the target table which has a field with "status".

Is that possible

Answer (score 0):

> > The possible values for fieldName are filtered by status. However, in this case, it is necessary to set a default value as being the PK of the target table which has a field with "status".

The targetTable and status are both defined in an `<appinfo>` annotation. Anything within an `<annotation>` tag is (by definition) targeted at the human reader or the processing application. It is completely ignored by the XML processor.

Presumably the `<appinfo>` annotation was generated by some application code. Can you add some code into that application to also generate the required default values? If not, you cannot use XML schema validation to supply the default values and you will need to do that in your processing application.

Comment: It is exactly that, but with a slightly difference: the target table has two PK, and that was what i could do right: what I needed do to was to set the default as being "PK1|PK2".
Thank you very much for your help :)